# Element changing position on refresh (Chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to figure out why in Chrome (and only in Chrome) an element of the header of my site change position after reloading. It has certainly something to do with the cache, since when I press Ctrl + Shift + F5 the layout fixes itself.
The troublesome part is this:

```css
#header-helpful {
  clear: right;
  color: #696969;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

header-helpful .action {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0px;
}

header-helpful .value {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-helpful">
  <div class="search-form">
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="https://rhesis.it/"></form>
  </div>
  <!-- end .search-form -->
  <div class="action">
    <div class="value">ISSN 2037-4569</div>
  </div>
```

The element `<div class=action">` looks fine on the first load, but after a reload goes down along with the `<div class="value">`.
I tried to look for a solution, but nothing I tried works.
You you want to check, the site is rhesis.it.
Do you have any idea? Any help appreciated!

**Edit 1:** The problem fixes itself just by increasing/decreasing the size of the window. But realoading it resurfaces.

**Edit 2:** here's what I (and other) see:

[first load or Ctrl + Shift + F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXrtU.png)

[after reloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4LcO.png)

Comment: It looks like the problem is with `line-height: 20px; `

Comment: I tried to put it to 0px, but the problem seems to remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the page with Chrome and the issue you describe never appears.
To check if cache is envolved try this: type in Chrome location the address adding a random number after a `?`, something like [rhesis.it?5675859](http://www.rhesis.it?5675859) or whatever number you want.

At this point your page should appear correctly paginated, than reload it...

If the problem disappear shurely the cache is envolved and should disappear deleting the whole cache of Chrome or the single envolved file of the cache.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. I tried your suggestion but to no avail. The problem persists: after reloading, the element goes down again. Other people tried it on their computer and could reproduce it.

Comment: At the end I solved by specifying the width of the `#header-helpful` element (in this case, 425 pixels were perfect). I don't really understand what was the problem, though.